# How can I (display) more than one checkbox on array?

Tags: php

How can I (display) more than one checkbox on array? The fruits included apple, orange, banana.

```
<?php
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fruits = $row['fruits ']
    }
   echo "<a class ='button' href='fruits.php?fruits=".$fruits."'>click</a>"; 
?>   

 <html>   
      <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" ><?php echo $_GET['fruits'] ?><br>    
 </html>
```

I want to display the result like this

[image: I want to display the result like this]

Comment: You need to replace `name="fruits"` with `name="fruits[]"`

Comment: admin admin  check the answer below

Comment: adminadmin  let me know check-box will made through `while()` data or through `$_GET` data? and  on button  which fruit need to be added as a get parameter? Also do you have all this inside a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]"><?php echo $row['fruits']; ?><br>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $fruits = $row['fruits'];
?>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" ><?php echo $fruits ?><br>    
<?php 
}
    echo "<a class ='button' href='fruits.php?fruits=".$fruits."'>click</a>"; 
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$fruits="your fruits array"
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($fruits )) { 
 echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$data['value']}'>" . $data['value'] . '</br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be like this.

```
    foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fruits" '.(($_GET['fruits'] == $fruit) ? "checked" : "") .'>'. $_GET['fruits'].'<br>';    
    }
```